# How to retrieve property names for all properties in a class in typescript excluding methods

Tags: typescript

I am trying to make my code as reactive as possible and need render my view based on the properties of a class, How do I retrieve the property names only form a class excluding methods etc.

for example.

```
export class Customer { 
    customerNumber: string; 
    name: string; 
    salesContact: string; 
    salesContactEmailAddress: string; 
    salesContactNumber: string; 
    execContact: string; 
    constructor(data?: any) {
        ...
    }

    toJSON() {
        ...
    }

    clone() {
        ...
    }
}
```

I need it to give me something the returned to be an Array of strings like this

```
fields: string[] = ["customerNumber", "name", "salesContact", "salesContactEmailAddress", "salesContactNumber", "execContact"];
```

Comment: This cannot be done. Typescript removes all type information from the script when it is compiled down to JavaScript. This limits the possibility for using reflection in this kind of way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JavaScript cannot hold the type information for a class in any way, so the short answer is that it's not possible in most cases.

Like [Thomas Devries mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45866789/how-to-retrieve-property-names-for-all-properties-in-a-class-in-typescript-exclu#comment78692282_45866789), you cannot perform real reflection in TypeScript.

The longer answer is that it's possible in *instances of a class*, and *as long as the properties have been initialized*. Then you just use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

This won't work:

```
class A {
  prop: string; 

  constructor() {
  }

  fn() {
    // ..
  }
}
const a = new A();
console.log(Object.keys(a)); // []
```

But this will:

```
class A {
  prop: string = "hello"; 

  constructor() {
    // Or here:
    // this.prop = "hello";
  }

  fn() {
    // ..
  }
}
const a = new A();
console.log(Object.keys(a)); // ["prop"]
```

In some instances, you might want to use [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames) too. There's some important distinctions between that and `Object.keys()`.

You can find even more information on enumerability [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties).